# User's Recently Visited Sites

Tags: navigation, site-usage, delegate-control

Anyone have any advice on the best way of tracking the recent sites a user has visited?

As part of my overridden Global Navigation delegate control, I'd like to create something similar to a breadcrumb, but instead displays the last 4 sites (SPWeb objects) the user visited regardless of hierarchical relationship.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling session state would have worked (I successfully implemented it this way first). But since I am working with a Standard license I was able to add a custom multivalued string property to the user profile property bag.

Then inside my delegate control I access the property with the following:

```
   SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
   UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
   UserProfile user = profileManager.GetUserProfile(false);
   ProfileValueCollectionBase siteValues = user.GetProfileValueCollection("LastFourSitesProperty");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build something to get this to work. In you custom global nav you could either store the navigation history in a cookie, in a db, in-memory or whatever you prefer.

Comment: I ended up enabling Session variables and using that method.  Does anyone have any words of warning regarding SharePoint and using Session state? I am a little leary of it because it is turned off by default.